# Does protobuf-net supports HybridDictionary?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a `HybridDictionary` object. Is it possible to use `Protobuf-net` to serialize `HybridDictionary` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not presently, and for good reasons:

- there is no way of understanding the data-contract of a `HybridDictionary`, since it only advertises `object` for both the key and value; protobuf-net *really, really* wants to understand the types involved
- it is not *appealing* to support it because in many cases it would require *boxing* - typically of the key (if not a `string`), but often of the value

As such, I would strongly recommend using `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or something that implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. In theory we could add APIs allowing you to *tell it* how to interpret the key and value (and obviously do the work to support that in the library), but I'm dubious as to whether that would *actually* be of *real* benefit. Frankly, I'm not sure that there is much purpose in using `HybridDictionary` these days (or for the last many years).

---

Actually, until 2.3.0, protobuf-net didn't *really* support `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` directly - at least, not in the way you might think: until the `map<...,...>` feature was fully implemented, what it *actually* saw was a list-like-thing, i.e. something that could be interpreted as a sequence of `{some type}`, with an `Add({some type})` method. In the case of dictionary, the `{some type}` happens to be `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`, which *in turn* can be interpreted as a tuple-like type (with members that exactly match the constructor, so infer the contract based on the constructor arguments). Conveniently, this turns out to be the exact same shape that `map<...,...>` uses, so this approach is interchangeable (data-wise) with the new approach preferred in 2.3.0 ([which is discussed more here](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/06/protobuf-net-gets-proto3-support.html)).